# Infinite Re-rendering of React Functional Component using Axios and useState/useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to create a React Functional Component using Typescript that will get data from an API and then send that data to another component, however, I am getting an error of "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Please offer any advice!

```
useEffect(() => {
    await axios.get('https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v3/quotes/random').then((resp) => {
            setQuote1(resp.data.data[0]);
        });
    getQuote();
}, []);
```

[Snippet of Code Causing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqKvS.png)

EDIT:
Here is the entire File where the error is occurring.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, CardGroup } from 'reactstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

import QuoteCard from './QuoteCard';

const MainQuotes = () => {
    const [quote1, setQuote1] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        await axios.get('https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v3/quotes/random').then((resp) => {
                setQuote1(resp.data.data[0]);
            });
        getQuote();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <CardGroup>
                    <QuoteCard quoteData={quote1} />
                </CardGroup>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    );
};

export default MainQuotes;
```

Comment: This code looks good. What exactly does the `setQuote1` do?

Comment: Are you sure t'he error is there?

Comment: Agree with @SuthanBala , post setQuote1

Comment: @LeshawnRice I just posted the entire file

Comment: @Jack_Lynch setting state causes a re-render, thats why its looping. If you add quote1 to the dependency array in your useEffect function it should work as expected

Comment: @LeshawnRice Doesn't adding it to the dependency array mean that whenever quote1 is updated it will cause a re-render?

Comment: @Jack_Lynch Oh I didn't realize the api endpoint was random, I'm gonna give an answer so its not all typed weird here

Comment: Jack_Lynch, it looks like the line with getQuote(); is left over from your original snippet. Can that be removed form your current code? (It might help with the error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of quote1 (I'm assuming it's a string) update to:

```js
const [quote1, setQuote1] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  function fetchQuote() {
    await axios.get('https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v3/quotes/random')
    .then((resp) => {
      setQuote1(resp.data.data[0]);
    });
  }  
  if (!quote1) {
    fetchQuote();
  }
}, []);
```

Because the response from the API is a random quote, you have to handle it based on the value of quote1. This should work because quote1 will only be updated after the component mounts (when the value is an empty string), and the following render won't update state, so `useEffect` won't loop infinitely.

Before the edit, I assumed the axios request was inside of the getQuote function. I have updated my answer to reflect the code you have posted.

If the API response was static, because the items in the dependency array only cause a re-render if they are changed from their current value, it only causes a re render immediately after the first state update.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it, still getting the infinite loop error

Comment: @jack_lynch wrap the axios request in a function called getQuote, I misread the code, thought it was in that func,

Comment: @Jack_Lynch check my answer now. It should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Can we get your entire code please? It seems the problem is going to be with your state hook and figuring out exactly what its doing.

My guess as of now is your state hook "setQuote1" is being invoked in a way that causes a re-render, which then would invoke your useEffect() again (as useEffect runs at the end of the render cycle) and thus, calling upon your setQuote1 hook again. This repeats itself indefinitely.

useEffect() allows for dependencies and gives you the power to tell exactly when useEffect() should be invoked.

Example: useEffect(() { code here }, [WATCH SPECIFICALLY THIS AND RUN ONLY WHEN THIS UPDATES]).

When you leave the dependency array empty, you tell the hook to run whenever ANYTHING updates state. This isn't necessarily bad but in some cases you only want your useEffect() to run when a specific state updates.

Something in your application must be triggering your useEffect() hook to run when you aren't wanting it to.

Comment: I just posted the entire file in an edit to the question

Comment: Stark, could you revise your answer to address the new code posted?